# Second Pivot Table with different Cache, on different Sheet, isn't being created

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am clearly missing something obvious.

I create a Pivot Table based on one sheet, and get all the data fields. Then, when I try to create a new Cache from a second source sheet, the new Pivot Table does not appear.

```
lRow = Sheets("Source1").Cells(Sheets("Source1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Sheets("Source1").Cells(1, Sheets("Source1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Manipulate data, including new columns
Set PRange = Sheets("Source1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(lRow, lCol + 2)
Set PDest = Sheets("Source1 Summary")

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= _
    PDest.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="Source1Pivot")

' Set up the table with the data fields, all works perfectly

'For the new Pivot Table:
lRow = Sheets("Source2").Cells(Sheets("Source2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Sheets("Source2").Cells(1, Sheets("Source2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = Sheets("Source2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(lRow, lCol + 1)
Set PDest = Sheets("Source2 Summary")

Set PCache2 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:= _
    PDest.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="Source2Pivot")
```

At this point, no new Pivot Table is created, and adding fields does not work. The macro ends with "Source2 Summary" being blank.

I did verify that the new lRow and lCol were pulling from the Source2 page. Can you see something silly that I've missed? I haven't been able to find any information about setting up a new pivot with new source on a new page... presumably because it usually just works!

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` above this snippet somewhere? If so , comment it out or put `On Error Goto 0` and then tell us what error (if any) you are getting. Also, it's best if you post your entire code or at least the bits with variable declarations in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting prange to two columns wider than your underlying data, so the PivotTable can't be created because there are no column headers for those blank columns.